# Change requires_model_validation in a project

Tags: python, django

I've uploaded from django 1.6 to django 1.7 and from python 3.2.3 to python 3.4.1.

Suddenly when I try to run the makemessages command to catch the translating messages I find this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Command Command defines both "requires_model_validation" and "requires_system_checks", which is illegal. Use only "requires_system_checks".
```

I've googled it and I don't find where or what I should edit. In fact I've never used this parameter so...

Any idea?

The traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/pablo/Workspaces/milao/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/home/pablo/Workspaces/milao/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/pablo/Workspaces/milao/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 238, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/pablo/Workspaces/milao/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 42, in load_command_class
return module.Command()
  File "/home/pablo/Workspaces/milao/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 228, in __init__
'"requires_system_checks".' % self.__class__.__name__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Command Command defines both "requires_model_validation" and "requires_system_checks", which is illegal. Use only "requires_system_checks".
```

Comment: Do you have custom management commands? If yes, please show them.

Comment: Nop... that's the point :S

Comment: Ok, thanks, could you show the complete traceback?

Comment: Question modified to add the traceback

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - uninstall Django completely and install again.

Comment: Same problem.... this problem is a headache :S

Comment: Ok, for me now too :) What if you try Django 1.7 on Python 3.2.3 - do you still see the issue?

Comment: I can't test the project with this configuration. I've uploaded because I needed a package that requires a newer version than python 3.2 :(

Comment: If really required for your headache I can test it right now :)

Comment: Okay, what if you rollback Django to 1.6?

Comment: It works great LOL.
Sometimes I hate computers. I want to leave them and move to the country to work as a farmer... :(

Comment: Working on the farm is a hard work too, believe me :) The issue with 1.7 is still open though.

Comment: Can you provide me a link to follow the issue? I saw One and I think it was closed :S

Comment: I meant your issue is still open. Downgrading is not really a preferred solution.

Comment: @PabloFlores are you using https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver by any chance? It appears to have a very similar looking issue: https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver/pull/99

Comment: NOP. Thats the only related thing I saw in my googling :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found the answer and it's not related with django core at all. I was not using any command. However one of my installed apps was using it. In this case it's django vinaigrette.

I'll upload the patch ASAP to port this app to django 1.7.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Paul Pepper for pointing me in the right direction. For me it was Django devserver causing the issue and updating to the latest version fixed it for me:

```
pip install -e git://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver.git@HEAD#egg=django-devserver
```

HEAD was commit e6c882fc11fba013b85d37f04db8f11b531eda9a at the time of this writing.